# What is the maximum possible brand rating?

Tags: virtonomics

What is the maximum possible brand for products? I am advertising some bread in a small city using TV advertising, and I reached a brand rating of more than 7. Can it go higher if I spend a larger amount on advertising? How high can the brand go? Is 10+ brand possible?